# Mystery Messages GET 200 from NodeJS / Express Server

Tags: node.js, http, express, morgan

I'm running a small Virtual Private Server in the cloud.  (Vultr)   It's a simple application serving html content for a small group of folks.  The server is running Node.js / Express (with Morgan to log all http requests).  I doubt our target audience for the site is even 10 users per day.  Note there is no database storage at this site. The site runs in a docker container.

As I check the site logs, I'm seeing very odd stuff.

Large quantity of these:

`GET https://www.cyberpolice.ir 200 38.171 ms - 32910`

[GWhois.org](https://gwhois.org/www.cyberpolice.ir+dns) tells me this is somebody in Tehran.

```
GET https://www.tasnimnews.com/ 200 780.989 ms - 32910
GET https://www.akamai.com 200 657.255 ms - 32910
GET https://www.varzesh3.com/ 200 5.752 ms - 32910
GET https://www.incapsula.com 200 269.104 ms - 32910
```

Generally I'll see a stack of these a few hundred at a time.  There are a lot of these, always of size 32910.

Anybody know what's going on here?  Why am I seeing these messages? Is somebody using my server for something nefarious?

Are there better settings for Morgan to fully identify what's going on here?

Frankly I don't understand a http request that will generate this GET response? What does that request look like?

Answer (score 1):

The first rule is that do not expose you Node JS server directly to the public traffic. You should use a reverse proxy server in front of your NodeJS server. The reverse proxy should be configured to accept requests only for a particular domain. Below is a sample Nginx config file to achieve this.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name your_domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not that it necessarily matters, but I didn't mention that I'm running this inside a docker container.   You are telling me what I shouldn't do, but not a mention of why.  (See 6 ea ? above) Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like your application has been exposed to some kind of traffic bot. Someone is generating a bulk of HTTP requests against your application with various host headers. So you have to configure your server stack to listen to a specific domain in order to get rid of those unwanted requests.

Comment: It will be really good if you are able to use a web application firewall like Cloudflare. Then you can configure your iptables to communicate only with firewall IPs. So you can completely get rid of malicious traffic since external systems will not be able to communicate directly to your server.